# imgur API: UserRemaining at 0 and never resets

Tags: imgur

I have been uploading images to **imgur** using `imgurpython` library with a free tier account, and everything was going well until `UserRemaining` hit zero last week.

Since February 27th, I have tried to continue my upload once a day but `UserRemaining` never resets, below is the response I receive:

```
   DEBUG 2021-03-05 13:51:20,190 : https://api.imgur.com:443 "POST /3/upload HTTP/1.1" 429 94
   ERROR 2021-03-05 13:51:20,198 : ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded!
{'UserLimit': '2000', 'UserRemaining': '0', 'UserReset': '3600', 'ClientLimit': '12500', 'ClientRemaining': '12499'}
```

The `UserReset` value never changes from `3600`, which i assume is the number of seconds that `UserRemaining` should have reset. I have now waited 6 days and it has not reset.

While the upload was working, I made sure to keep to within the 52 image upload per hour limit by putting `time.sleep(71)` in my loop, and I was successful in uploading images for a number of days uninterrupted.

1. Does anyone know when the `UserRemaining` will reset?
2. Searching through [imgur API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/), I could not find an explanation of what `UserRemaining` defines, and what the limit means. Is it an account lifetime limit?
3. I emailed **imgur** customer support, and their response was to direct me to ask my question here with the `imgur` tag, because my question is API related.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55417370/1270789) might be a dup, but it doesn't have an upvoted answer; see the [Rate Limits](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#rate-limits) page. Perhaps you have been banned for skirting too close to the limit for too long?

Comment: Thanks for the Rate Limit page link, I've just re-read it. So it seems that `UserRemaining` should be reset after an hour, and that ties in with the 3600 seconds number, but it never does.